# Using the @CompositeProperty annotation for a Map<String, Set <String>> in a Spring Boot application using Kotlin and Neo4j

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have a question about using @CompositeProperty for a Map<String, Set< String >> in a Spring Boot application with Kotlin and Neo4j.

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.0-SNAPSHOT"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.30"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.4.30"
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.12.+")
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
}
```

I want to have a Map in an entity, which contains a String as key and a Set of Strings as value (Map<String, Set< String >>). (It is the last attribute in the class)

```
@Node("Skill")
data class Skill(

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @JsonIgnore
  val id: Long?,

  @Property("uuid")
  val uuid: UUID?,

  @CompositeProperty
  val description: Map<String, Set<String>>?,
```

router:

```
@SpringBootApplication
internal class SkillApplication {

    @Bean
    fun route(handler: SkillHandler) = router {
        GET("$SKILL_ROUTE/$ID_PATH_PATTERN", handler::findByUuid)
        GET(SKILL_ROUTE, handler::findAll)
        POST(SKILL_ROUTE, handler::create)
    }

    companion object {
        const val SKILL_ROUTE = "/skill"
        const val ID_PATH_VAR = "id"
        const val ID_PATH_PATTERN = "{$ID_PATH_VAR:${ID_PATTERN}}"
    }

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<SkillApplication>(*args)
}
```

handler:

```
@Component
internal class SkillHandler(val service: SkillService) {

  fun findAll(request: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
    return ok().body(service.findAll())
  }

fun create(request: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
    return request.bodyToMono<Skill>()
      .flatMap {
        service.create(it).flatMap { skill ->
          ok().body(skill.toMono())
            .switchIfEmpty(badRequest().build())
        }
      }
  }
```

Service-Layer (Relationship "Hierarchy" is only a first test with relationships):

```
internal class SkillService(val repo: SkillRepository) {

  fun findAll() = repo.findAll()

fun create(skillRequest: Skill): Mono<Skill> {
    val skill2 = Skill(
      null,
      UUID.randomUUID(),
      mapOf("en" to setOf("english description")),
      emptySet()
    )
    val hierarchy: Set<Hierarchy> = setOf(Hierarchy(null, UUID.randomUUID(), skill2))
    val saveSkill: Skill = skillRequest.copy(uuid = UUID.randomUUID(), hierarchy = hierarchy)
    return repo.save(saveSkill)
```

What I noticed when looking at the stored information on the database explorer is that the map is stored under properties, which should not be the case.

```
{
  "identity": 12,
  "labels": [
    "Skill"
  ],
  "properties": {
"description.en": [
      "english description 2",
      "english description 1"
    ],
"uuid": "2e7924c1-6e53-4faa-be93-8081107279f5"
  }
}
```

The record should actually look like this:

```
{
    "uuid": "eeaacee9-782a-42e9-b5a2-5bf2b837addc",
    "description": {
        "en": [
            "english description 2",
            "english description 1"
        ]
```

However, when retrieving the data via the rest endpoint, I get the following error message.

```
"status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "JSON encoding error: class org.neo4j.driver.internal.value.StringValue cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (org.neo4j.driver.internal.value.StringValue is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: class org.neo4j.driver.internal.value.StringValue cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (org.neo4j.driver.internal.value.StringValue is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap') (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.test.skill.entity.Skill[\"description\"]->java.util.HashMap[\"en\"]->java.util.LinkedHashSet[0])",
```

My guess is that I need the Neo4jPersistentPropertyToMapConverter interface for this. Am I right with this assumption, and how would an implementation look concretely?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Reading https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#custom.conversions.composite-properties, it seems only Object-typed values are supported. You might need `Neo4jPersistentPropertyToMapConverter` to customize the behavior indeed.